# Mailgun setup but receiving two errors with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailgun

After setting up Mailgun, I am receiving two errors that I am unable to resolve at the moment. Below are the errors with the code relating to them:

Mailgun::CommunicationError (404 Resource Not Found):

`app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:11:in introduction_email'`
  `app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:29:in create'`

```
def introduction_email(user)
    @user = user
    mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new ENV['api_key']
    message_params = {:from   => ENV['PIP_username'],
              :to     => @user.email,
              :subjet => "Sample Mail using Mailgun API.",
              :text   => "This mail is sent using Mailgun API via mailgun-ruby."}
    #The line below is the line of concern for the second error.
    mg_client.send_message ENV['domain'], message_params 
end


def create 
    @article = Article.create(article_params)
    @article.user = current_user
    if @article.save
      #The line below is the line of concern for the second error.
      UserMailer.introduction_email(@article.user).deliver_now 
      flash.notice = "Article #{@article.title} has created!"
      redirect_to community_path
    else
      flash.notice = "Try Again!"
end
```

If you happen to see any issues, have any ideas or need more code, please let me know =) Looking to learn why these are causing an issue and to resolve them, thank you!

Joe

**EDIT**

Due to changes I've made while working on a tutorial, I realized my mailer is within UserMailer but I am putting the controller information within the articles_controller. I've since switched, created an ArticleMailer and replaced the code there but still the same issue.

Comment: Have you considered using the mailgun_rails gem? With that gem, you can set `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun` in your environment config, and implement email delivery as normal (for action mailer) while sending through mailgun.

Comment: The process I have mentioned includes using the mailgun-rails gem, which I have in my gemfile. I believe I should be leaving it at :smtp though? I changed it to try and still receive the same 404 error though =( I appreciate it!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Hey there, sorry I've been working on another aspect but still need to solve this. I had this setup and it still did not work. I will probably return to this in another day or two =)

Comment: No problem. I've added a bit more on the configuration to my answer. I use this method in one of my apps, so it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `mailgun_rails` gem and set `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun` in your environment config, you should be able to deliver emails in the Rails default way:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def introduction_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail({
      :from    => ENV['PIP_username'],
      :to      => @user.email,
      :subject => "Sample Mail using Mailgun API.",
      :text    => "This mail is sent using Mailgun API via mailgun-ruby."
    })
  end
end
```

Then:

```
UserMailer.introduction_email(@article.user).deliver
```

**Edit** You also need set the following environment variables from Mailgun for the gem to work:

```
MAILGUN_API_KEY
MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN
MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD
MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT
MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER
```